# Restore the cursor back to the position it was when Hotkey was first triggered?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

I am trying to move my cursor vertically down till it gets to the bottom of the monitor (1500) then have it wrap around  by moving it back to the initial position.

The problem am having is that every time wheeldown is triggerd MouseGetPos is also revaluated.

I can try to evaluate MouseGetPos when the script is first run but it would still not be accurate as the script could be running for
an hour before wheel down is ever triggerd.

Here is my code so far, Thanks!

```
WheelDown:: 
MouseGetPos, xpos1, ypos1
xpos2 := xpos1
ypos2 := ypos1

MouseMove, % xpos2 +0, % ypos2 +90


if (ypos2 > 1500)
MouseMove, %xpos1%, %ypos1%
Return

esc::ExitApp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other approaches may be possible, but the simplest answer is likely to explicitly define whatever the "initial position" you want to scroll back to is. One method of doing this is to monitor key states when calling `WheelDown::`:

*ex. cursor_looping.ahk*

```
esc::ExitApp

WheelDown::

    MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos

    ; True or False
    marker_key_is_down := GetKeyState("F7")
    reset_key_is_down := GetKeyState("F4")

    ; Set a static y position
    if (marker_key_is_down)
        {
        initial_y_position := ypos
        }

    ; Return to "indefinite" scrolling
    if (reset_key_is_down)
        {
        initial_y_position :=
        }

    MouseMove, % xpos +0, % ypos +90

    if (ypos > 1500)
        MouseMove, %xpos%, %initial_y_position%

Return
```

In short, with the example script above, if you press e.g. <kbd>F7</kbd> then scroll down once with the mouse wheel, the original position of the mouse will be stored in `initial_y_position`. This value is persistent. It won't be overwritten unless you:

- Press <kbd>F7</kbd> and scroll down again to set a new position (the previous position does not need to be cleared).
- Press e.g. <kbd>F4</kbd> and scroll down to go back to default behavior (i.e. the mouse will just remain at the bottom of the screen, no matter how long you scroll).
- Close the script.

*Caveats*

- While the F-Key/Scroll down method is pretty intuitive to use in my estimation, remember that it does run for every scroll. You need to release ex. <kbd>F7</kbd> after the first scroll for things to work correctly (assuming your mouse is already located at the `y` position you want).
- To clear a position, remember you need to press ex. <kbd>F4</kbd> and scroll down at least once. Multiple scrolls won't harm anything in this case.
- `GetKeyState()` only works for single keys, so your choices for keys to monitor may be limited.
- `ypos > 1500` is rather important. This can affect how the script operates. For instance, if Windows is enlarging your desktop, a 1920x1080 resolution may actually only offer ~800 pixels of scroll distance at 150% size for wrapping to work correctly (so. ex. `ypos > 800` not `ypos > 1080`). In this case, it would be impossible to scroll to 1080 and thus this section would never be triggered.

---

*References*

- *[GetkeyState()](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm) (AutoHotkey)*